# Gorm extremely slow

Tags: go, go-gorm

Gorm seem to be extremely slow.

```
type Ad struct {
    AdId        string `json:"adId" gorm:"column:adId"`
    Attributes  string `json:"attributes" gorm:"column:attributes"`
    Title       string `json:"title" gorm:"column:title"`
    Description string `json:"description" gorm:"column:description"`
    Image       string `json:"image" gorm:"column:image"`
    Url         string `json:"url" gorm:"column:url"`
    Price       int    `json:"price" gorm:"column:price"`
    Address    string    `json:"address" gorm:"column:address"`
    Latitude   float64   `json:"latitude" gorm:"column:latitude"`
    Longitude  float64   `json:"longitude" gorm:"column:longitude"`
    PostedDate time.Time `json:"postedDate" gorm:"column:postedDate"`
}

db.Table("Kijiji").Find(&listing).Where("adId = ?", m["id"][0])
```

The last time takes almost 60s to query. Whereas if I used "database/sql" `mysql.QueryRow()` its less than 500ms.

Any idea why?

Update:

The slowdown happens in this `callback_query.go` It appears that this function is looping through the entire table of 20k records.

```
func queryCallback(scope *Scope) {
    ..........
        if rows, err := scope.SQLDB().Query(scope.SQL, scope.SQLVars...); scope.Err(err) == nil {
            defer rows.Close()
            columns, _ := rows.Columns()
            for rows.Next() {
                scope.db.RowsAffected++

                elem := results
                if isSlice {
                    elem = reflect.New(resultType).Elem()
                }
                scope.scan(rows, columns, scope.New(elem.Addr().Interface()).Fields())
            ..................
        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Take a debugger and find at what step it takes 60 seconds to evaluate.

Comment: Inside Gorm? Or in my own code.

Comment: In the code that you observe as "slow". `db.Table("Kijiji").Find(&listing).Where("adId = ?", m["id"][0])` if this statement is slow - debug through its every function call.

Comment: So debug through it, 60 seconds would be impossible to not spot.

Comment: Will give it a try. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: its the .Find() that is slow

Comment: Now step into it and find why `.Find` is slow. Continue until you find the root of the problem. If you still need any help by then - share the new details.

Comment: ORM isn't intended to be used in golang first of all.

Comment: @LaevusDexter I will regret it, but "isn't intended" by _whom_?

Comment: @zerkms Added update and found out where the slowness is happening

Comment: @zerkms Thank you, we got it fixed...

Comment: @Telenoobies but hopefully the main lesson here is that debugging can get you really far in researching your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did it backwards. `Find` executes the query and fetches the rows. You wanted `db.Table("Kijiji").Where("adId = ?", m["id"][0]).Find(&listing)` to apply the where condition *before* fetching everything.

Comment: The Gorm tutorials are not very explicit.. I will give this a try. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mind pointing out where it says .Where must come before .Find  (I know It makes sense, but i want to see where you got the answers from)

Comment: All of the examples at http://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Where show it first, and http://gorm.io/docs/method_chaining.html shows some idea of the design.

Comment: "where you got the answers from" --- it should also come from your debugging session as well: if `Find` binds results to a value - those results should have been fetched already.